# Convert HTML to XLS from a webpage

Tags: c#, .net, html, xls

Hey guys, i dont have a clear definition of what my client wants but i figured i could get a dialogue going.

> so my client wants to take some html from a page and convert it to and xls form.  all the data and content is from their own website/portal and they just need the reports converted to xls for accounting or something.
>
> Oh yeah, id like to keep this in .NET C# please...

has anybody done this? What options are there?

Thanks guys!

Comment: You'd probably should ask your client from what data the Web pages are generated. Probably there is already a database?

Comment: the data is coming from a ms sql db, i want the functionality to be automated, like "click here" and then get prompted.

Comment: So then it's probably much easier to connect directly to the MS-SQL database from Excel with the same queries that are used in the HTML frontend (instead of first generating HTML and then parse the HTML again).

Comment: thats what they used to do, but they want to prevent their clients from having sql connection strings, username, and password.  they want to generate the reports(export to excel) and send them over.  hence the new functionality

Answer (score 2):

You can grab that external page by using XHR, parse it's HTML and to return your data with content-type = `"application/vnd.ms-excel"`

Comment: can you explain, i get the content-type, but what would be the process to take the data coming from the DB that is populated the datagrid, and create a download that has that corresponding data in an xls file.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that data are from a remote webserver; since you get database access, you just need to render a datagrid into a page and download it with appropriate content-type. Take a look here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/ExportASPNetDataGridToExcel11222005041447AM/ExportASPNetDataGridToExcel.aspx

Comment: hahaha thanks for the link, i actually was looking at before i read your comment and saved the link....

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach is to to just output a html table, and set the mime-type to application/vnd.ms-excel as @Rubens Farias said. If you have access to the existing application it's easy to extend, if not you must grab the html and parse it.

Excel can parse html tables without problems, even with formatting:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <td style="background-color: red">Content in cell</td>
            <td>Cell 2</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

My company's developed an HTML to XLS API called DocRaptor that can do this. DocRaptor is a Ruby on Rails project, but we use HTTP POST requests to generate documents. We've got a C# example on our documentation page, which you can see here:

[DocRaptor C# example](http://docraptor.com/documentation/examples_csharp)

And here's a link to our homepage:

[HTML to Excel with DocRaptor](http://docraptor.com/html-to-excel)

Answer (score 0):

You can highlight any table and copy/paste it into Excel and Excel should handle the conversion nicely.

You can also provide .CSV versions of your reports.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Libreoffice converting the html to xlsx.   You can even preserve date formats.  I did long ago write this up ... I just re-posted it at 
http://wjmceachran.com/2020/04/create-excel-files-from-legacy-system-with-libreoffice/